# How to extrapolate a reasonable price given data points?

Tags: calculus, statistics

I work as a math tutor, and the kids get cards for getting work done. They then are able to exchange those cards for gift cards. 
The exchange policies being (10,5),(19,10),(27,15),(35,20),(42,25),(55,35),(75,50)
|(cards,gift card balance).
Recently a student had 100 cards, which was exchanged for a 100$ gift card, but I felt that it should've actually been more than that given the exchange policies.
So to get a more proper exchange rate, I thought it would be a good idea to use newtons method to extrapolate a better exchange rate for 100 cards, but I couldn't figure out or find out how to do this with data. So I'd like to know how one would do this or if there is a better way.

Comment: You have both $(10,5)$ and $(10,19)$? I'm not sure I understand. I don't think I quite get what the notation means.

Comment: @Eff my guess would be the first point should be reversed

Edit: I missed the second confusing set of points

Comment: @tzamboiv Still, then I don't understand the points $(35,55)$ and $(75,50)$. Maybe the latter should be reversed as well.

Comment: oops, fixed now

Comment: The first step should be to plot the points in a coordinate system. That in itself will be a good exercise for the kids. Then you can find the best fitting line (regression) or another kind of curve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a naive polynomial approximation, I found that $f(x) = \frac{x}2 + \frac{x^2}{400} $ gives a reasonable approximation of your data points. Using this, I found that the pair (100,75) is a reasonable extrapolation for 100 cards.

[image: Naive Polynomial Approximation]

Comment: I haven't used this website before so I don't know if it's customary to thank people for a helpful answer, but thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could fit a regression and extrapolate outside the range of observation (which I've always been advised not to do).

```
x <- c(10, 19, 27, 35, 42, 55, 75)
y <- c(5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 35, 50)
# plot(y~x)  # quick look
fit <- lm(y ~ x+I(x^2))
# summary(fit)  # quick summary
# plot(fit)  # if you care about checking residuals
predict(fit, newdata=data.frame(x=100))
```

which returns 72.06341. The naive model says 100 for 100 is quite generous.

I chose degree 2 because it encourages increasing reward at a higher rate when students turn in more cards.